# chunking trick using the zip() and iter() functions

Tags: python

In this [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/everything-you-should-know-about-python-zip-function-fba0e4e13361), it uses this below code:

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
list(zip(*[iter(n)]*2))
```

It gives the following interpretation for this code:

> This repeats the same iterator n times so that each output tuple has
> the result of n calls to the iterator. But with each call of such
> iterator we are consecutively losing its initial element.

I am wondering whether it should be

> This repeats the same iterator two times so that each output tuple has
> the result of two calls to the iterator?

If I am wrong, can someone give a better explanation of how he refers "the same iterator n times" and "each tuple has n calls".

Comment: Unroll it to multiple lines: `a = b = iter(n); res = list(zip(a, b))`. Does it make more sense this way? (Agree that the description is highly confusing, given `n` is the name of the list in the code.)

Comment: @tobias_k Isn't your code says that the same iterator is used twice rather than n times? That's where I get confused with.

Comment: Yes, the blog says, "n times", so was struggling to understand the real meaning of it.

Comment: It's inconsistent with the example, but what they mean is that you can replace the `2` in the code with any other number. Was that was confused you? If it's more, please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, that was my confusion.